# iPhone object not dying

Tags: iphone, animation, uiviewcontroller, profiling, automatic-ref-counting

I am using ARC in my app.
Now I faced a real problem. I need to animate two view controllers from left to right. So I just animate the the two views in button action like,

```
// thanks to stackoverflow for this code

test *control = [[test alloc] initWithNibName: @"test" bundle: nil];
control.view.frame = self.view.frame;
control.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), self.view.center.y);
[self.view.superview addSubview: control.view];

// Animate the push

[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];

[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(pushAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
control.view.center = self.view.center;
self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x - CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), self.view.center.y);

[UIView commitAnimations];

- (void) pushAnimationDidStop: (NSString *) animationID finished: (NSNumber *) finished context: (void *) context 
{
  [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

and in the second view controller I did the same but change the animation direction.

My real problem is when I run this code, every time I create an object of the another class and it is not deallocating. By profiling this code, found that the every time the object is alive and it is not dying and the memory allocation get increasing.

Comment: where did you allocate your *control??? is it inside your button action??? if so, then, your problem lies there, because your code alloc a new controller each time you press the button to animate. if you still want to alloc the view in the button for whatever reason u might had, use if(!yourViewController){ allocate your controller } so that the app only alloc you a new controller if the old one already automatically deallocated by arc (arc automatically dealloc object's that is remain unactive/ or not having it views loaded) *CMIIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the allocation instrument with reference count recording enabled. Then evaluate where the offset differs from your expectations, based on that data.